# OptionMenu de Tkinter no muestra la primera opción

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un  `OptionMenu()` en `Tkinter` que toma las cuatro opciones a elegir de una lista. El problema es que la primera opción, (`RI` en mi caso) solo aparece como opción por defecto pero al desplegar el menú no aparece en la lista desplegable y si selecciono otra opción ya no aparece más (solo me da a elegir las otras tres pero no aparece la primera). Este error aparece cuando importo `ttk` solamente.

Este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Alta de Clientes/Proveedores")
ventana.geometry("800x600+110+110")
#ventana.transient(IMenu.ventana)

etiqueta03 = Label(ventana, text="Responsable Iva :").place(x=50,y=120)

#boton01=button(ventana,text="Abrir").place(150,200)
boton3 = Button(ventana,text="Volver",command= ventana.destroy).place(x=270,y=360)

respo=StringVar(ventana)
opciones = ['RI', 'MO', 'CF','EX']


entra03 = OptionMenu (ventana, respo,*opciones).place(x=170,y=120)
respo.set(opciones[0])
print (respo.get())
ventana.mainloop ()
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema común por usar el `*` a la hora de importar, lo cual no deja de ser peligroso porque hay casos como este que no sabes que espacio de nombres usas. Tal y como tienes tu código estas usando el `OptionMenu` 'modificado' de `ttk` y el problema está en que a diferencia del `OptionMenu` definido en `Tkinter` el tercer parámetro del constructor de `OptionMenu()` es en realidad el item por defecto. Es decir el prototipo del constructor es:

```
def __init__(self, master, variable, default=None, *values, **kwargs):
```

Por lo tanto tienes dos opciones:

- ❶ **Usar el `OptionMenu` de `ttk`**

  En tu caso deberias llamar al contructor así:

  ```
  entra03 = OptionMenu (ventana, respo, opciones[0], *opciones).place(x=170,y=120)
  ```

  Si quieres otro item por defecto solo cambia el parámetro `opciones[0]` por el que desees. Si no quieres ninguno puedes hacer:

  ```
  entra03 = OptionMenu (ventana, respo, None, *opciones).place(x=170,y=120)
  ```

  Es decir, tu código queda:

  ```
  from tkinter import *
  from tkinter.ttk import *

  ventana = Tk()
  ventana.title("Alta de Clientes/Proveedores")
  ventana.geometry("800x600+110+110")
  #ventana.transient(IMenu.ventana)

  etiqueta03 = Label(ventana, text="Responsable Iva :").place(x=50,y=120)

  #boton01=button(ventana,text="Abrir").place(150,200)
  boton3 = Button(ventana,text="Volver",command= ventana.destroy).place(x=270,y=360)

  respo=StringVar(ventana)
  opciones = ['RI', 'MO', 'CF','EX']

  entra03 = OptionMenu (ventana, respo, opciones[0], *opciones).place(x=170,y=120)

  print (respo.get())
  ventana.mainloop ()
  ```
- ❷ **Usar el `OptionMenu` definido en `Tkinter` a secas:**

  Debes cambiar los import (de todas formas sería recomendable) y hacer algo así:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  import tkinter.ttk as ttk


  ventana = tk.Tk()
  ventana.title("Alta de Clientes/Proveedores")
  ventana.geometry("800x600+110+110")
  #ventana.transient(IMenu.ventana)

  etiqueta03 = tk.Label(ventana, text="Responsable Iva :").place(x=50,y=120)

  #boton01=button(ventana,text="Abrir").place(150,200)
  boton3 = tk.Button(ventana,text="Volver",command= ventana.destroy).place(x=270,y=360)

  respo=tk.StringVar(ventana)
  opciones = ['RI', 'MO', 'CF','EX']

  entra03 = tk.OptionMenu (ventana, respo, *opciones).place(x=170,y=140)
  respo.set(opciones[0])

  print (respo.get())
  ventana.mainloop ()
  ```

Visualmente no son iguales y también varía la forma de definir la opción por defecto. Esta sería una comparativa simple entre las dos:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("OptionMenu")
ventana.geometry("100x100+110+110")
ventana.configure(background='black')

opciones = ['Opción 1', 'Opción 2', 'Opción 3', 'Opción 4']

#OptionMenu de tkinter sin las modificaciones de ttk
var1=tk.StringVar(ventana)
var1.set(opciones[0])
menu1 = tk.OptionMenu (ventana, var1, *opciones).place(x=30,y=20)

#OptionMenu con las modificaciones de ttk
var2=tk.StringVar(ventana)
menu2 = ttk.OptionMenu (ventana, var2, opciones[0], *opciones).place(x=30,y=60)

ventana.mainloop ()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mas claro imposible !!!!!!

Comment: Si te ha sido útil @MartinEduardoLaspiur recuerda que puedes aceptar la respuesta para que otros usuarios con tu mismo problema encuentre la solución fácilmente. Puedes mirarte [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) si no sabes como funciona. Saludos.